# SP_EXECUTESQL and Output Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I would like get the ID from the query, but I am getting a NULL, where is my mistake?

```
DECLARE @TblZimz    NVARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @IdModul    INTEGER
DECLARE @Id         INTEGER

SET @TblZimz        = '_ZIMZ000001'
SET @IdModul        = 1
--SET @Id               = -1

EXECUTE [InsertZimz] @TblZimz, @IdModul, @Id OUTPUT




ALTER PROCEDURE [InsertZimz]
@TblZimz    NVARCHAR(256)
, @IdModul  NVARCHAR(256)
, @Id       INTEGER OUTPUT

            DECLARE @SqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @SqlQuery = 'SELECT TOP (1) ([ID]) FROM ' + @TblZimz + ' WHERE [ModulId] = ' + @IdModul

        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SqlQuery, N'@Id INTEGER OUTPUT', @Id OUTPUT
```

why the @Id Paramter is alwasy null? I cant see my mistake?

Comment: where is your insert query?

Comment: If you are going to allow the table name as parameter (not a great idea) you need to wrap the parameter inside QUOTENAME at the very least to help prevent sql injection.

Comment: Also, use top without an order by is not a good practice. You don't know which row is going to be returned and it can change between executions. You should always have an order by when using TOP.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First, select the desired `id` in an output variable using `@Id = ([ID])` then assign this `@Id OUTPUT` value in the `@Id` variable using `@Id = @Id OUTPUT`. Also, you should pass data in where clause using a variable to avoid sql injection problem like `[ModulId] = @IdModul` (i.e. you should not concatenate it like `[ModulId] = ' + @IdModul`). try this :

```
DECLARE @SqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SqlQuery = 'SELECT TOP (1) @Id = ([ID]) FROM '
                + @TblZimz + ' WHERE [ModulId] = @IdModul'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL
  @SqlQuery,
  N'@Id INT OUTPUT, @IdModul INT',
  @IdModul = @IdModul,
  @Id = @Id OUTPUT
```

Check details of `SP_EXECUTESQL` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Comment: @Id = ([ID]) perfekt!

Comment: but, what do you mean with: "You are not selecting the id in a variable also you should pass data in where clause using a variable to avoid sql injection problem"

Comment: @MeerArtefakt elaborated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Like [Deepak's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27486184/1501497) answer, but easier:

> EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL   @SqlQuery,
> N'@Id INT OUTPUT,  @IdModul INT',
> @IdModul OUTPUT,  @Id

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of returning a dynamically defined proc's return value (rather than select results):

```
CREATE PROC p AS return 3
GO
DECLARE @proc varchar(30) = 'p', @retval int
DECLARE @qry nvarchar(max) = 'EXEC @i = ' + @proc --plus params as needed
EXEC sp_executesql @qry, N'@i INT OUTPUT', @retval OUTPUT
select @retval      --returns 3
```

(Use case: to do a full "data run," I cursor through a list of procs I run, each of which returns a row count for logging purposes. Chased my tail quite a while before cracking this.)